# Replace linebreak with substring from another string in sequence using Excel

Tags: excel, substitution

I want to replace linebreaks on string 1 with substrings from string 2. The substitute sequence should be in order based on linebreaks on string 2.
example/idea should look like this:

string 1:

```
date1|date2|date3|date4|date5|
```

string 2:

```
sentence1|sentence2|sentence3|sentence4|sentence5|
```

expected result:

```
date1sentence1date2sentence2date3sentence3date4sentence4date5sentence5
```

The formula that I used which I know is incomplete:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1,MID(A1,6,1),"?")
```

Thanks in advance....

Comment: Substituted will not do this unless there is a fixed number of breaks.  You would need one substitute for each line break.  Do you have TEXTJOIN?

Comment: @ScottCraner Sorry, I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to mean as I am a bit new to Excel formulas.  I didn't use TEXTJOIN.  Any formula would do as long as it works.  The number of dates should match with the number of sentences and are separated by linebreaks (w/c i used as markers to know the sequence).  This is an exported CSV file from a CRM. I just wanted to merge the dates and its corresponding sentences. Thanks.

Comment: The question is, "Is there always 5 dates and sentences?"  If the can vary one cannot use SUBSTITUTE alone.

Comment: No, sometimes 3 dates and 3 sentences, or 8 dates and 8 sentences. It usually matches. Here is the actual screenshot  https://www.screencast.com/t/2PxxMgsvt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have access to CONCAT you can use this array form:

```
=CONCAT(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"|",REPT(" ",999)),(ROW($ZZ1:INDEX($ZZ:$ZZ,LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"|",""))))-1)*999+1,999))&TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"|",REPT(" ",999)),(ROW($ZZ1:INDEX($ZZ:$ZZ,LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"|",""))))-1)*999+1,999)))
```

Being an array formula it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

[image]

If one also has Access to the dynamic array formulas then they can use:

```
=CONCAT(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"|",REPT(" ",999)),SEQUENCE(LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"|","")),,1,999),999))&TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"|",REPT(" ",999)),SEQUENCE(LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"|","")),,1,999),999)))
```

and it no longer needs the CSE entry.

---

If it is always 5 items per string then one can use SUBSTITUTE:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"|",TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"|",REPT(" ",999)),1,999)),1),"|",TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"|",REPT(" ",999)),999,999)),1),"|",TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"|",REPT(" ",999)),2000,999)),1),"|",TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"|",REPT(" ",999)),3000,999)),1),"|",TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"|",REPT(" ",999)),4000,999)),1)
```

It require the use of one Nested SUBSTITUTE per item.

Comment: I know your formula works, but mine isn't I'm not sure if its the Excel version or I edited your formula the wrong way. This is my edited version: `=CONCATENATE(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1,MID(A1,23,1),REPT(" ",999)),(ROW($ZZ1:INDEX($ZZ:$ZZ,LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,MID(A1,23,1),""))))-1)*999+1,999))&TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(B1,MID(A1,23,1),REPT(" ",999)),(ROW($ZZ1:INDEX($ZZ:$ZZ,LEN(B1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(B1,MID(A1,23,1),""))))-1)*999+1,999)))` but the result is only a 1 liner https://www.screencast.com/t/e2w31uSBLXB5

Comment: Not `CONCATENATE` it should be `CONCAT` if you do not have `CONCAT` then your will need vba to do this.

Comment: Many thanks, you are a savior.  May I ask what's the least Excel version that I can use this formula? Other alternatives like google sheets? Thanks again

Comment: It seems to be working in Google Sheets but is missing one line of sentence in the end. https://www.screencast.com/t/FnVc6AyXygWM

Comment: That is because your test data shows the the `|` also on the end of the strings.  If this is not the case then one needs to add `+1` after both `LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"|",""))`

Comment: To solve the missing last sentence.  I added a linebreak to both ends of the string & it works like a charm.  Again, thank you so much, Scott. - and yes your last comment works =)